# How do you retrieve Method Args/Params by name in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How you get individual parameters out of a Method param map in Elixir?

```
def do_something(%{"my_params" => params}) do

  IO.puts  "this is your param = #{my_params[param_name]}"
  IO.puts  "this is your param = #{my_params[:param_name]}"
  IO.puts  "this is your param = #{my_params.param_name}"

end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ in Elixir one cannot use curly braces instead of `do-end` block, because `do` is actually _a keyword parameter having a key `do`_.

Answer (score 1):

If there are few, it’d be better to pattern match them in place:

```
def do_something(%{"my_params" => %{"param_name" => value}) do
  IO.inspect value, label: "this is your param"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me little bit to find, it's pretty simple.  Map syntax.

```
def do_something(%{"my_params" => params}) do
  IO.puts "this is your param = #{my_params["param_name"]}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need.

If you don't want error when the key not exists, use `my_params[:param_name]`(which will return nil in this case), otherwise, `my_params.param_name`.

If you want a default value when the key not exists, use `Map.get(map, key, default \\ nil)`.